# How to force the height of element with different device modes?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, youtube-iframe-api

I am using angular-youtube-embed and together with Chrome Dev tools (toogle device mode feature), I wanted to test how the youtube element would look.

I have

```
<div class="fixed-header my-video">
    <div style="padding:0px;">
        <youtube-video  video-url='vm.videoUrl' player-vars="{controls : 0}" 
           player-width="'100%'" player-height="'180px;'"></youtube-video> 
    </div>
</div>
```

and my css is :

```
.my-video
{
  height:180px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  background:grey;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding:0px;
}
```

and

```
.fixed-header{
 margin-top:43px;
}
```

Now the above looks fine when I toggle the device mode to iPhone5. When I switch to iPhone6 then the video height is set to 180px (as I have defined above) but looks smaller.

On an iphone6 setting height to around 207px (approx 31% of view height looks fine).

So I tried using 31vh for height in my css which works but it does not pass it on to my angular-youtube-embed component even when I set it (by my controller) to

```
 player-height='vm.height' // vm.height = "31vh"
```

In fact the height is set to 150px.

So my question is is there a way to set the height of the angular-youtube-embed element so that it takes 31% of the view port?

Answer (score 1):

use media query

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .my-video {
   height:360px;
   width:100%;

}


@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .my-video {
    height:180px;
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately as angular-youtube-embed calculates the heights as well, this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who helped.

I set

```
 vm.height = (0.5625 * $window.innerWidth);
```

and this works and keeps the aspect ratio (with width 100%) at 16:9.

Answer (score 0):

Try using height as in %age rather than in pixels. As in pixels it gives specific dimension but when specified in %age component will adjust itself based on windows relative size